# How to convert filename with invalid UTF-8 characters back to bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, filesystems

How do I convert the output of `os.listdir` to a list of `bytes` (from a list of Unicode `str`s)? It has to work even if the filename is invalid UTF-8, for example:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> open(b'\x80', 'w')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name=b'\x80' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> os.listdir('.')
['\udc80']
>>> import sys
>>> [fn.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()) for fn in os.listdir('.')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udc80' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
>>> [... for fn in os.listdir('.')]
[b'\x80']
```

So what do I need to write to the `...` above to make it work?

Please note that it's not an option to rename the file, to use Python 2.x, or to use ASCII-only filenames in this case. I'm not looking for workarounds, I'm looking for the code in place of the `...`s.

Comment: have you tried to get bytes in the first place: `os.listdir(os.fsencode(os.curdir))`?

Comment: Or just `os.listdir(b'.')`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an error handler; in this case the `surrogateescape` error handler looks appropriate:

> **Value:** `'surrogateescape'`
>   **Meaning:** `On decoding, replace byte with individual surrogate code ranging from`U+DC80`to`U+DCFF`. This code will then be turned back into the same byte when the`'surrogateescape'` error handler is used when encoding the data. (See [PEP 383](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383) for more.)

The [`os.fsencode()` utility function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsencode) uses the latter option; it encodes to `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` using the surrogate escape error handler when applicable for your OS:

> Encode filename to the filesystem encoding with `'surrogateescape'` error handler, or `'strict'` on Windows; return `bytes` unchanged.

In reality it'll use `'strict'` only when the filesystem encoding is `mbcs`, see the [`os` module source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c9650423c336/Lib/os.py#l752), a codec only available on Windows.

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> ld = ['\udc80']
>>> [fn.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()) for fn in ld]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udc80' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
>>> [fn.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding(), 'surrogateescape') for fn in ld]
[b'\x80']
>>> import os
>>> [os.fsencode(fn) for fn in ld]
[b'\x80']
```

Comment: Thank you, `surrogateescape` indeed works (and `surrogatepass` doesn't give the result I expect) on my machine.

Comment: `os.listdir()` uses `os.fsdecode()` internally therefore `os.fsencode()` should be used. As @pts said: surrogatepass-based approach produces a wrong result here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: right, removed the `surrogatepass` option altogether.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [os.fsencode(fn) for fn in os.listdir('.')]
[b'\x80']
```

There is also a corresponding `os.fsdecode` for conversion in the other direction.

Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsencode

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the filenames from `os.listdir` in bytes, it has that option.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> *path* may be either of type `str` or of type `bytes`. If *path* is of type `bytes`, the filenames returned will also be of type `bytes`; in all other circumstances, they will be of type `str`.